# Apache Ignite over hive database : How to connect Hive database in Ignite?

Tags: hive, ignite

How to connect Hive database in Ignite framework?
Can we use already existing hive database and hive tables over Ignite?

Answer (score 2):

There are two options I think:

1. Load all data from Hive database and recreate the same schema in Ignite and stream all data to it with [DataStreamer](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.3/docs/data-streamers##ignitedatastreamer)
2. Connect to Hive Database by using [CacheJdbcPojoStore](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.3/docs/3rd-party-store#section-cachejdbcpojostore) and [Hive JDBC Driver](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.2/bk_data-access/content/hive-jdbc-odbc-drivers.html).